# Each group of order 8 has a subgroup of order 2 and a subgroup of order 4.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So, I was trying to prove the following theorem:

> Let $G$ be a group of order $8$. So $G$ has a subgroup of order $2$ and a subgroup of order $4$.

First I proved that if a group has a finite even order, it has an element $g_0$ of order $2$. So $H=\{g_0,e\}$ is a group of order $2$. Now I'm trying to find the group of order $4$. By Lagrange theorem I can understand that:

$$|G|=|H|\cdot |G\,:\,H| \Rightarrow |G\,:\,H|=4$$

So we have $4$ Cosets. But how to continue from here? I feel like I miss the last one-two lines of the proof.

Comment: Do you know that nilpotent groups (and in particular $p$-groups) have non-trivial centres? If yes, it would be better and more instructive to prove that nilpotent groups (and in particular $p$-groups) have subgroups of each possible order. (In fact, this holds for a broader class of groups.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you can show that $G$ has a subgroup of order 4 directly. If $G$ has an element of order 4 or 8 then we are already done [why?]

Otherwise let $\pi$ and $\alpha$ be two distinct elements in $G$ of order 2. So $\pi = \pi^{-1}$ and $\alpha = \alpha^{-1}$. Then $\pi\alpha$ must have order 2 as well, lest there be an element of order 4 or 8 which would imply that we are done. This implies that $\pi \alpha = \alpha \pi$. [Indeed, for any elements $a,b,c$ in any group $G'$, if $ab=ac$ then $b$ must equal $c$. But  here $(\pi \alpha)(\pi \alpha) = 1$, while $(\pi \alpha)(\alpha \pi) = (\pi \alpha)(\alpha^{-1}\pi^{-1}) = 1$. So indeed, $\pi \alpha = \alpha \pi$.] This implies that $H \doteq \{1,\alpha, \pi, \pi\alpha \}$ is closed under composition, and as every element in $H$ has its inverse in $H$, it follows that $H$ is a subgroup, and has order 4.

Answer (score 7):

If $G$ has no subgroup of order $4$, then every $g\ne e$ has order $2$. Then for any $g,h$,
$$
e=(gh)^2=ghgh=ghg^{-1}h^{-1},
$$i.e. $G$ is abelian. Then $\{e,g,h,gh\}$ would be a subgroup of order $4$.

Comment: why every $g\neq e$ has order $2$ if $G$ does not have subgroup of order $4$? Also why $ghgh=ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$?

Comment: @Baduk: Apply Lagrange's Theorem. Also, we have $x^{-1}=x$ iff $x^2=e$. (Why?)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** No group has exactly two elements of order two.

> Assume no subgroup of order four exists. Apply Lagrange's Theorem. Apply the hint. See @Mike's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3114192/104041).

Reference for the lemma that is the hint:

Exercise 4.61 of Gallian's *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Eighth Edition)"*

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1154361)

Comment: @Gibbs, I've included a reference.

Answer (score 0):

suppose non identity element  ${a\in G}$ and

- if ${|a|=8}$, then ${|a^4|=2}$
- if ${|a|=4}$ then ${|a^2|=2}$
- so, we found that there is an element k which has order 2. now the subgorup generated by another element h must have order 4 (according to Lagrange's Theorem)